# Conseguir o documente por um iframe

Tags: javascript, html

Como eu faço para criar um script que retorne com o documento de um iframe. Tentei este código mas não funcionou:

```
function getDocumento(ifrane){
    return iframe.document;
}
```

Comment: O src de um iframe é uma url de um site.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sugiro usar uma biblioteca para isso. Com jQuery seria algo como:

```
function getFrameContents(iframe){
    return $(iframe).contents();
}
```

Na versão javascript puro têm de ter em conta browsers diferentes. Teste assim:

```
function getFrameContents(iframe){
   var iframeDocument = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document
   return iframeDocument;
}
```

Repare que no seu código tem o nome do argumento da função com "n" em vez de "m".

Tenha em conta que se a `iframe` estiver num domínio diferente vai ter limitações de [CORS](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/145493/129).